# JNI issue: symbol lookup error by FileHandle in C++ DLL

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface, filehandle

I made JNI functions and linked them with the c++ dynamic library successfully. I got all of them working just fine, but I had an issue for one function, I got symbol lookup error from the FileHandle class that I used in the c++ that I use to read data from file.
Knowing that it's working on a normal c++ project, but not in the DLL.

/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /home/.../NetBeansProjects/TRIOGUI/dist/libNativeAdd.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5Gdsii9GdsParserC1EPKcN7SoftJin10FileHandle8FileTypeEN5boost8functionIFvS2_ESaIvEEE
Java Result: 127

Can anybody help me please? :)

Comment: You should provide the code that you are using... both on the Java and on the C++ side.

Comment: This is a function in a library I am using in my project. I referenced it in the c++ compiler in the project properties and the library works fine with all its functions in a normal project, but when I make my project a DLL file, all the functions and the Native Functions I made works correctly, except for this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, thanks for you all.
The library I was using had a library file "somefile.a" that I was missing from the library folder.
I got the library, included it in the project and it worked fine :)

Again, Thank you guys for trying to help :)

Answer (score 3):

I find your symbol highly suspicious. Incorrect mangling. How did you get it? Is it copy&paste from somewhere? Did you try to hack it? `10FileHandleF8ileType` should be `10FileHandle8FileType`. Then it turns to a valid symbol `Gdsii::GdsParser::GdsParser(char const*, SoftJin::FileHandle::FileType, boost::function >)`

Comment: yes, you were right about the 10FileHandle8FileType, and I edited it.
and yes, that this is a function in GDSParser class, and I gave it the correct parameters. In the normal c++ project, it works correctly, but when I use it in the DLL, it gives me that error :(

Comment: What do you mean "edited it" ? So is it correct as a symbol in the SO file or not?

Comment: I think you will have to explain what is the "normal project" which you are referring to as fully working. If it is a statically linked app, then you may have just wrongly set up search paths for DLLs.